# IdentityServer4 + Blazor on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, identityserver4, .net-5

I have an application in Blazor that uses PublicOrigin.
In .Net Core 3.1 it works correctly.
In .Net 5.0, when I run from the command line, it works. But when I use IIS, it doesn't.
I've tried all the examples I found, but none worked.

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
    await next();
});
```

OR

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
    ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("example.com");
    
    await next();
});
```

OR

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.SetIdentityServerOrigin("https://example.com");
    await next();
});
```

Can anybody help me?

**Relevant parts of the log file**

```
Exception: 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Version doesn't map to a known HTTP protocol. (Parameter 'version')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpProtocol.GetHttpProtocol(Version version)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpRequestFeature.get_Protocol()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Protocol()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.IsEmptyHostAllowed(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

Comment: As the exception said,you need to check the version you passed to GetHttpProtocol with the known HTTP protocol version of IIS,they are not matched.

Comment: You ever find a cause? I’m running into the same error. We are using asp.net and upgrading to core 5 is producing these errors. We are struggling to find a cause